# How to make corner for Arc

Tags: ios, objective-c, geometry

I have made an arc like below. By specifying the Radius, Start angle, End angle

```
    CGContextAddArc(ctx, self.frame.size.width/2  , self.frame.size.height/2,
 self.radius, 2*M_PI, 3*M_PI/2-ToRad(angle), 0);
```

Now **i want to make the corner of arch rounded**. So need of drawing circles on the both ends. Because I'm using frame dimensions giving constants wont work.

[image]

Comment: Does you graphic library provide pen characteristics setting? Like PS_ENDCAP_ROUND in Windows GDI.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try to set the Graphics State Parameter CGContextSetLineJoin to round:  `CGContextSetLineCap(ctx, kCGLineCapRound);`

Here is my research based on your question. The method resides in the drawRect: method, I wrote a short method to abstract it, in order to give only the parameter startAngle, endAngle and radius to the method. Of course it ca be refined.

I provided you a picture from the output of this method.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    float startAngle = 0;
    float endAngle = 60;
    float radius = 50.0;

    CGContextRef ctx = [self drawRoundedArcWithStartAngle:startAngle endAngle:endAngle radius:radius];
    CGContextStrokePath(ctx);
}

- (CGContextRef)drawRoundedArcWithStartAngle:(float)startAngle endAngle:(float)endAngle radius:(float)radius {

    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    //    [CGContextAddArc(ctx, self.frame.size.width/2  , self.frame.size.height/2, radius, 2*M_PI, 3*M_PI/2-(angle * M_PI / 180), 0)];

    CGContextAddArc(ctx, self.frame.size.width/ 2, self.frame.size.height/2, radius, (startAngle * M_PI / 180), (endAngle * M_PI / 180), 0);
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(ctx, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, 20.0f);
    CGContextSetLineCap(ctx, kCGLineCapRound);
    return ctx;
}
```

Hope it helps!

[image: Arc with rounding. Output from the method above.]

Answer (score 1):

You can set it easily by

Objective-C

```
CGContextSetLineCap(context, kCGLineCapRound);
```

Swift

```
context?.setLineCap(.round)
context?.addArc(center: center, radius: radius, startAngle: startAngle, endAngle: endAngle, clockwise: true/false)
```